# Rails and LDAP integration with Devise finding records in LDAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I need your help. In my app I'm using devise_ldap_authenticatable gem for Devise.

After configuring device.rb in initializers and ldap.yml still can't find records in LDAP I'm sure I should (I can find them via  LDAP explorer using the same configuration and credentials). Can you please advice me, what I do  wrong in my config, that I'm not searching properly. Which attribute should I change (it's not the problem with authentication but with finding records in LDAP).

My config:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  ##allow_unauthenticated_bind: false
  ##group_base: DC=zzz,DC=yyy,DC=xxx
  #Requires config.ldap_check_group_membership in devise.rb be true
  # Can have multiple values, must match all to be authorized
  ##required_groups:
    # If only a group name is given, membership will be checked against "uniqueMember"
    ##- cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=zzz,dc=yyy,dc=xxx
    ##- cn=users,ou=groups,dc=zzz,dc=yyy,dc=xxx
    # If an array is given, the first element will be the attribute to check against, the second the group name
    ##- ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]
  ## Requires config.ldap_check_attributes in devise.rb to be true
  ## Can have multiple attributes and values, must match all to be authorized
  ##require_attribute:
    ##objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    ##authorizationRole: postsAdmin

## Environment

development:
  host: host_name
  port: 389
  attribute: mail
  base: DC=zzz,DC=yyy,DC=xxx
  admin_user: user_name
  admin_password: *******
  ssl: false
```

In my log I can see:

```
LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: mail=login
LDAP: LDAP search for login: mail=login
LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
LDAP: Authorizing user mail=login,DC=xxx,DC=zzz,DC=yyy
LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
```

Many thanks,
T

Comment: Log message clearly says " Not authorized because not authenticated.". You have set login attribute as "mail". Are you providing admin_user value an email ?

Comment: Hi @Roshith! Yes, my admin_user is set as an e-mail. Where should I set login attribute as "mail"? In ldap.yml I have attribute set as mail should I change in other place as well?